# parallel_tests RSpec improve performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, parallel-testing

I have a suite of tests for a controller that makes calls to an external sandbox api for testing, which makes the performance rather slow. I'd like to improve performance by allowing parallel_tests to not only run suites in parallel, but individual `describe`s.

For example:

```
RSpec.describe FooController do
    describe '#index' ...
    describe '#create' ...
end
```

Because the `#index` and `#create` tests do not share any memory space, it's fine to parallelize them. One option is:

```
RSpec.describe 'FooController#index' do
    describe '#index' ...
end

RSpec.describe 'FooController#index' do
    describe '#create' ...
end
```

but this makes the tests look awkward and a pain to read through. Is there a way I can easily have `parallel_tests` run each `describe` in parallel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the maintainer of parallel_tests also has a gem designed just for this: https://github.com/grosser/parallel_split_test

After installing via `gem install 'parallel_test_split'` you can simply run `parallel_split_test`

Reduced a slow (but small) suite from 12 seconds to 6